# How to replace the contents in a frame on button click in Pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

So I have two frames,the first frame includes all the header elements and the second frame includes an image with two buttons.This is the content of my first screen. Now when I click on the the button the contents in the second frame should be replaced with a .py file which has a list of attributes.The first frame contents would be same throughout all the screens and only the second frame should be changing.This is the code I have for the first screen:

```
import sys
import os
import taurus
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from taurus.external.qt import Qt
from taurus.qt.qtgui.panel import TaurusForm
from taurus.qt.qtgui.application import TaurusApplication

form_class = uic.loadUiType("FirstScreen.ui")[0]                 # Load the UI
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #self.editValue.clicked.connect(self.openForm_clicked)
        self.setWindowTitle('FirstScreen')
        self.button1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color:#00FFFF;}")
        self.dateTime.setText(QtCore.QDate.currentDate().toString())
        self.timeLabel.setText(QtCore.QTime.currentTime().toString())
        self.button2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color:#00FFFF;}")
        myPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8('Sample.png'))
        myPixmap=myPixmap.scaledToHeight(100)
        self.pic.setPixmap(myPixmap)





app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = MyWindowClass(None)
myWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Could you let me know how I can load the second frame with a .py file on button click. The other .py file which I am trying to load is also created using Pyqt.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [signals and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html). ie use clicked signal and call a function eg: onClick .

**self.button_name.clicked.connect(self.onClick)**

In the  function call

```
            self.second_frame = second_ui_class()
            self.second_frame.show()
```